# Why does the difference of two rounded numbers not respected the rounded values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rounding, addition, subtraction

I created a round function and it works fine in simple rounding.

If I round two numbers A and B, and then I add them, the result is fine.

But, if I "subtract" them, the result is weird. It is not rounded like it should.

I show you the function:

```
function round(x, p) {
    return parseFloat(x.toFixed(p));
};
```

Weird result:

```
var a = 5.0007;
var b = 2.048
var result = round(5.0007, 3) - round(2.048, 2);

// expected result: 2.951
// obtained result: 2.9510000000000005
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joaorodr84/10nefsye/6/)!

Would you please help me understand why this subtraction shows a weird result?

Thanks

Comment: What weird results do you get? Please put them in your post.

Comment: @Bergi, Sorry, I had the fiddle so I supposed everyone would open it. But you are right, I just added the weird result in the post. Thanks

Comment: @Juhana, Thanks, but this does not explain why it has this error. :s

Comment: Yes, It's true. I just read it. Thank you and sorry for the duplicated question. :)